# How implement rotation like in Transformer

Tags: konvajs

I want to implement rotation by manually entering the degree of rotation in the field.

I have tried these solutions:

https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/26

https://konvajs.org/docs/posts/Position_vs_Offset.html

But, they affect parameters skew.
How to implement changing properties similarly to Transformer when rotating shapes with the mouse.

I tried using the `_handleMouseMove` method of the Transform class, but it pulls a chain of methods.

Tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: You may just need to manually calculate new {x,y} of a node. How exactly do you want to rotate? Around what point? And what node?

Comment: Делать перерасчет - пробовал, но это не совсем то.

Точка опоры должна быть в центре фигуры, но возникают проблемы с типами звезда и треугольник.
Так же для корректной трансформации нужно расчитывать skewX, и skewY

Comment: Your problem is still not clear. You can use offset if you want to rotate around center without any manual calculations for {x,y}. What problems do you have with stars? Why do you need skewX, skewY? Can you make a demo of what you are trying?